# how to assign values to bootstrap switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below are the codes for my bootstrap switch and "save" button. Firstly, I want the users to use my bootstrap switch and choose either the "on" or "off" state. Once the user has chosen a state, he will click the submit button. If the user clicks "on", I will create the attribute "value" with a value of "true". If the user clicks "off", I will create the attribute "value" with a value of "false". I will then issue a post HTTP request with the value of the attribute to the API method to insert the value into the correct table in the database. However, I keep receiving the value "false" even when the user clicks "on"

```js
$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

        var $collectedIsVisible = '';
    
        if ($('#testInput').is(':checked')) {

            $collectedIsVisible = $('#testInput').attr('value', 'true');           
        }
        else {
            $collectedIsVisible = $('#testInput').attr('value', 'false');         
        }
```

```html
<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="testInput">Yes or No</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testInput" name="testInput" checked/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
```

[image]

Comment: I tried, In the web api method, the value of checkbox will always be true even if the user clicks "off"

Comment: (You’re aware that with a normal form submission, you would not get any name=value pair for an _unchecked_ checkbox to begin with, right?)

Comment: there are tons of plugin which have bs-switch UI for checkboxes. have a look at bootstraptoggle.com if you like to use.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

        var $collectedIsVisible = '';
    
        if ($('#testInput').is(':checked')) {

            $collectedIsVisible = $('#testInput').attr('value', 'true');           
        }
        else {
            $collectedIsVisible = $('#testInput').attr('value', 'false');         
        }
```

```html
<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="testInput">Yes or No</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testInput" name="testInput" checked/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="save();" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you are declaring a variable with $ jquery doesn't do that you have to use 'var' keyword. Second, instead of setting the checkbox value attribute you can make a variable as you are making "collectedIsVisible" and pass this variable to your AJAX call. and you can use this code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

        var collectedIsVisible = '';
    
        if ($('#testInput').is(':checked')) {

         collectedIsVisible = true; 
          console.log(collectedIsVisible);
        }
        else {
            collectedIsVisible = false 
          console.log(collectedIsVisible);
        }       
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="testInput">Yes or No</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testInput" name="testInput" checked/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this might help you.